# Replace SNMP4J Vector<VariableBinding> with ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

Can somebody show the correct syntax to replace a vector with an ArrayList?

Original code -

```
StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
        msg.append(event.toString());
                Vector<? extends VariableBinding> varBinds = event.getPDU()
                .getVariableBindings();
```

Have tried -

```
List<String> variables = new ArrayList<>();
for (VariableBinding binding : event.getPDU().getVariableBindings()) {
    variables.add(String.valueOf(binding.getVariable()));
}
```

But multiple issues (diamond operator not supported, can convert ArrayList to String).  Netbeans / JDK1.6

And tried -

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(varBinds) = event.getPDU().getVariableBindings();
```

But unexpected type, required variable found value, cannot find symbol variable varBinds.

Thoughts appreciated

Regards
Active

Comment: This seems like a good opportunity to upgrade to a supported Java version.

Comment: Hello Shivam, tried your ArrayList (see my original post) but multiple issues, probably syntax on my part

Answer (score 1):

The diamond operator was not available in JDK 1.6. You need to define the ArrayList using the old style generics form:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

List<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Following the docs of SNMP4J at

http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/index.html

The `event.getPDU().getVariableBindings()` will return an Vector of [VariableBindings](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/VariableBinding.html)

If you want to store that in an ArrayList of VariableBindings you could do

```
List<VariableBinding> variables = new ArrayList<String>(event.getPDU().getVariableBindings());
```

However if you are looking to store a string representation of the VariableBinding you can retrieve the string representation of the underlying [Variable](http://www.snmp4j.org/doc/org/snmp4j/smi/Variable.html)

e.g.

```
List<String> variables = new ArrayList<String>();
for (VariableBinding binding : event.getPDU().getVariableBindings()) {
    variables.add(binding.getVariable().toString());
}
```

It all depends on what you're wanting to achieve.

Comment: cannot find symbol classList

Comment: You need to import java.util.List and ArrayList. Will edit Answer

Comment: Thanks Spangen, can you show me the entire command including the getPDU part?

Comment: What is the full type of VariableBinding including its package?
For instance is it a `org.snmp4j.smi.VariableBinding` ?

Comment: yes, snmp4j, returns multiple variables

Comment: Much appreciated Spangen, it was the string representation I was after. Working perfectly.

Comment: Great! Please can you consider marking my answer as the accepted one?